# How to find the modified rows in a similar tables in ms sql server?

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have two similar tables, one hold's yesterday data and other one holds today's data. There is change in data on a daily basis. Below is the structure of the data

There is three column in tables. I need data like:

```
Employeeid old_dat_col1 old_data_col2 new_data_col1 new data_col2
```

However `employee_id` is not a primary key and there can be multiple instances of it. But the combination of all 3 column is a primary key. I need to show old data and new data for corresponding employee in a same row.

How can I do this?

Comment: add sample data with expected output

Comment: Show sample data of the both the tables and your expected result

Answer (score 0):

Because you don't have a primary key, getting everything in one row is a bit tricky.  In my opinion, the right approach is something like this:

```
select y.*, t.*
from yesterday y full join
     today t
     on y.Employeeid = t.Employeeid and
        y.col1 = t.col1 and
        y.col2 = t.col2
where t.Employeeid is null or t.Employeeid is null;
```

However, that puts the values on a separate row.  How to get them one one row?  Well, that is arbitrary, because if you have multiple rows for an employee and something changes, you don't know which changed.  But, here is one method:

```
select max(employee_y) as employee_y,
       max(col1_y) as col1_y,
       max(col2_y) as col2_y,
       max(employee_t) as employee_t,
       max(col1_t) as col1_t,
       max(col2ty) as col2_y
from (select y.employeeId as employeeid_y, y.col1 as col1_y, y.col2 as col2_y,
             y.employeeId as employeeid_y, y.col1 as col1_t, y.col2 as col2_t,

             row_number() over (partition by (case when y.employeeid is null the 't' else 'y' end) order by coalesce(y.col1, t.col1)
                               ) as seqnum
      from yesterday y full join
           today t
           on y.Employeeid = t.Employeeid and
              y.col1 = t.col1 and
              y.col2 = t.col2
      where t.Employeeid is null or t.Employeeid is null
     ) ty
group by employeeid, seqnum;
```

Note:  The above queries assumes that the columns do not take on `NULL` values.  That can easily be incorporated, but makes the queries more complicated (and perhaps needlessly so).